# To update the value of variable?

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
l=[21,23,25,30,33,45,56,67,70,77--------------------]
h=35
r1=[]; r2=[]
for i in range(len(l)):
   if(l[i] < h):
      r1.append(l[i])
   else:
      r2.append(l[i])
print r1
print r2
```

The result obtained was:

```
[21, 23, 25, 30, 33]
[45, 56, 67, 70, 77----------------------]
```

Now I need to increment h=35 so that when it reaches 46 its output must be

```
[21, 23, 25, 30, 33,45]
[56, 67, 70, 77----------------------]
```

Next when h reaches 57

```
[21, 23, 25, 30, 33,45,56]
[67, 70, 77-------------------------]
```

So as a whole the final result should display:

```
[21, 23, 25, 30, 33]
[45, 56, 67, 70, 77-----------------]

[21, 23, 25, 30, 33,45]
[56, 67, 70, 77---------------]

[21, 23, 25, 30, 33,45,56]
[67, 70, 77--------------]

[21, 23, 25, 30, 33,45,56,67]
[70, 77--------------]

[21, 23, 25, 30, 33,45,56,67,70]
[77--------------]

[21, 23, 25, 30, 33,45,56,67,70,77]
[-----------------------]
```

What will produce such a result in python without passing it as a function parameter?can anyone suggest a code for it..........

Comment: make h the parameter of a function and call the function with the desired h

Comment: Wrap your code in a function and pass the value of `h` during function call.

Comment: if l is a long list of numbers which i don't know earlier.How can i pass it as a parameter??

Comment: is there any way where i could increment h value & keep on checking the condition until end of list.because my list is very long..

Answer (score 5):

In addition to jimifiki's answer, the code can be simplified and made more pythonic.

```
def funct(h):
    l = [21,23,25,30,33,45,56,67,70,77]
    r1=[]; r2=[]
    for x in l:
        if x < h:
           r1.append(x)
        else:
           r2.append(x)

    print r1
    print r2

for h in (35,45,55,65):
    funct(h)
```

Comment: +1 for not using indexes. Note that you need `for x in l` not `rl`

Answer (score 3):

Make `h` the parameter of a function and call the function with the desired `h`.

```
def funct(h, l):
    r1=[]; r2=[]
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if(l[i] < h):
           r1.append(l[i])
        else:
           r2.append(l[i])
    print r1
    print r2

longL = [21,23,25,30,33,45,56,67,70,77]
for h in (35,46,57,68):
    funct(h, longL)
```

Comment: @devnull As the answer is fixed now, your comments are obsolete. Maybe it would be worth noting that.

Comment: @jimifiki if l is a long list of numbers which i don't know earlier.How can i pass it as a parameter??

Comment: @glglgl I made the change a couple of minutes after commenting. (The revisions would reveal that.)

Comment: def funct(h, l): ... and then you call the function with funct(35,[21,23,...]) or funct(h,longL)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
l=[21,23,25,30,33,45,56,67,70,77]

def splitAt(data, point):
    less = [c for c in data if c < point ]
    more = [c for c in data if c >= point ]
    return [less,more]

print(splitAt(l, 35))
```

Split at returns an array of two arrays, the first being the values less than and the second being the values greater (or equal to)

```
[[21, 23, 25, 30, 33], [45, 56, 67, 70, 77]]
```

Comment: I would return a tuple of lists, not a list of lists.

Comment: Nevertheless, this is not a bad answer, but it iterates over `l` twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that your input list is sorted (or that it's feasible to do so), and that your splitting value is also sorted, then you can use `bisect`, and keep searching from the previous point. You'll need to adapt the following to use whatever behaviour is required for out of boundaries:

```
import bisect

def split_list_at(L, points):
    pos = 0
    for val in points:
        pos = bisect.bisect_left(L, val, pos)
        yield L[:pos], L[pos:]

l=[21,23,25,30,33,45,56,67,70,77]
h = 35,46,57

for first, second in split_list_at(l, h):
    print first, second
```

And, as a test (to see if if you get the right results for boundaries):

```
for idx, lists in enumerate(split_list_at(l, xrange(100)):
    print idx, lists
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def spli(L,st,nd):
    if L[0]<st<=nd<=L[-1]:
        i = (j for j in xrange(1,len(L)) if L[j] >= st).next()
        first  = L[:i-1]
        second = L[i-1:]
        while second and second[0]<nd:
            first.append(second.pop(0))
            yield first,second

l=[21,23,25,30,33,45,56,67,70,77]
print '\n'.join('{}\n{}\n'.format(*x) for x in spli(l,35,67))
```

result

```
[21, 23, 25, 30, 33]
[45, 56, 67, 70, 77]

[21, 23, 25, 30, 33, 45]
[56, 67, 70, 77]

[21, 23, 25, 30, 33, 45, 56]
[67, 70, 77]
```

The expression `(j for j in xrange(1,len(L)) if L[j] >= st)` is a generator that yields all the indexes of the elements of L that are greater or equal to the value `st`.
Putting `.next()` after this expression gives only the first of these indexes.
Having this first index, we start at the preceding one. There surely is a preceding one because the condition `L[0]<st` assures it.
We start at the preceding one because I put the instruction `first.append(second.pop(0))` that moves the first element of **second** to the end of **first** before the yielding of **first** and **second**.
And I choosed this succession of instructions  in order that the test `second[0]<nd` won't let the result `L  []` to be yielded

.

This code uses a value `nd`. In case you don't want to stop the yielding of splitted list until the end of the original list is attained, it can be modified to:

```
def spli(L,st):
    if L[0]<st:
        i = (j for j in xrange(1,len(L)) if L[j] >= st).next()
        first  = L[:i]
        second = L[i:]
        while second:
            yield first,second
            first.append(second.pop(0))
```

.

In this solution, knowing in advance the values 35,46,57 and writing them in the code isn't required. The algorithm is so that these values are found during execution, whatever they are.